# Why does the scanner gets te wrong input?

Tags: java, if-statement

The input is a word. If the word is hello it should print: Hello sir etc if the input is not hello it should print: why dont you say hello?
The problem is that it always prints: Why dont you say hello? Why is this?

```
Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
String word=input.nextLine();
if(word=="hello"){
    System.out.println("hello sir have a good day");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Why dont you say hello?");
}
```

Comment: Have you considered option that it may not be scanner that is giving wrong result? Maybe it is way you are testing it?

Comment: depperm: that 's not the problem in this code, he's using == while he should be using equals

Comment: Changing nextLine to next gives same problem. How should i test it? what do you mean?

Comment: Instead of `if(word=="hello")`, use `if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(hello))`

Comment: can you add `System.out.println(word);` at the end? Maybe the scanner gets some line-breaker symbols...

Comment: @JohnnyAW: nope. he's doing a referential comparison, while he wants to do a comparison on value.

Comment: Take a look at [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: @Stultuske it doesn't matter in this case, since the `String`s are saved in the String-pool and no new Objects should be created here

Comment: This is not a real duplicate question. This is related to the internal implementation of Scanner that creates a new String using the operator new. So the returned string is not the same of internal string pool

Comment: @JohnnyAW: yes, it does matter in this case, and yes, it will solve his problem. If you don't believe me, just run the snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the method `equals()` instead of comparing the two strings with the operator `==`

The == operator check for identity of the two operands.

In this case a **new String** is created when you call the method `nextLine` on `Scanner`. So calling the operator `==` results in a false results, instead calling `equals` that check for internal content of both strings returns true.

Comment: Instead of reposting same answer all over again you can simply post comment with link to canonical question: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Bookmark it in your browser, you will need it.

Comment: Because here I explained why the results are different. Internally Scanner.nextLine calls inderectly the substring of String that create a new String. That's why I answered here. It is specifically to scanner this response. In addition is not a wrong answer so I don't understand the minus.

Comment: Thx to all i was very stuck. So the problem is the location where it is stored. == checks out the location

Comment: Yes == check for location, equals check for content

Comment: "Because here I explained why the results are different." you add that part after my comment. Now your answer looks better. My comment was indented to discourage answers which basically say only *use euqlas instead of `==`*.